# "asp-format" not applied to tag helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime-format

I'm facing a problem using "asp-format" tag with taghelper element in my mvc 6 project.

The idea is to format a date input element this way:

```
<input asp-for="StartDate" asp-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
```

This "StartDate" property is in my model, declared this way:

```
public DateTime StartDate {get; set; }
```

For a strange reason, this element is never formatted, and is presented always like this:

```
---> 02/29/2016 00:00:00
```

So I created a viewmodel class and defined a property to hold the entire person model.

```
public class PersonViewModel 
{
    public Person Johndoe {get; set; }
}
```

And using this class in the view, the formatting works.

```
<input asp-for="Johndoe.StartDate" asp-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />

---> 29/02/2016
```

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution for this using the tag helpers?  I just tried doing it the way you have at the start of the question and it worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can provide the format in model itself like

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

  public DateTime StartDate {get; set; }
```

and in your view simply like

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.StartTime)
```

2) You can also do this without providing date format in model class

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Comment: I'm actually using mvc 6 with tag helpers approach, so I cant use html helpers.

Comment: I'm also not a big fan of defining the display format in the model.  What if I want to use the same model and display the date in two different formats (i.e. with the time in one place and without the time in another).

Answer (score 4):

Add type = date which will format the date

```
<input asp-for="StartDate" type="date" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: It seems that `type="date"` (`asp-format` has no effect) fixes the problem in this case, but what about in general?

Comment: "In general", these are two entirely different approaches. `type=date` will format the date in the _user's_ chosen format. The `asp-format` approach formats it in the developer's choice.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

and

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

In my viewmodel.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime From { get; set; }
```

My view looks like this:

```
   From: <input asp-for="From" />
```

Answer (score 0):

asp-format worked with me only when I added [DataType(DataType.Text)]

This will render the input as text not date or datetime, native browser date picker will not appear, but you can use third party date picker, for example [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)